# How to get Active Admin to store a hash of Boolean key/values in a serialized object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activeadmin

I used to have all my models accolades stored as boolean columns, and I'm trying to make it a bit cleaner and more manageable. This will only be edited by admins, It's only user-facing for display purposes.

I'd like this to be a list of checkboxes, but I'm having trouble updating them from ActiveAdmin.

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ACCOLADES = :great_guy, :smashing_haircut, :trimmed_nails,
              :fresh_breath, :nice_shoes
  serialize :accolades, Hash
  store_accessor :accolades, User::ACCOLADES
```

admin/user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  menu parent: "User Information"

   ...

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Basics" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :website
      f.input :email
    end
...
    f.inputs "Accolades" do
      User::ACCOLADES.each do |accolade|
        f.input accolade, as: :boolean, checked_value: 'true', unchecked_value: 'false'
      end
    end
  end
```

This renders a list of checkboxes as expected, but it is creating the wrong "layer" of names and ID's

```
<li class="boolean input optional" id="user_great_guy_input"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="user[great_guy]" value="false"> 
  <label for="user_great_guy" class=""><input type="checkbox" name="user[great_guy]" id="user_great_guy" value="true">Great Guy</label>
</li>
```

How can I get a list of checkboxes that update the serialized hash?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Turns out it was a couple of things. Between us, another dev and I misread the Store documents and were working on a different assumption of its inner working.

With this, I was attempting to create the hash to send and store in `.accolades` but that was incorrect. Adding :accolades and ACCOLADES to the strong params in admin/user.rb fixed this issue and it now updates as expected with

```
f.inputs :accolades do
  f.input :great_guy, as: :boolean, checked_value: 'true', unchecked_value: 'false'
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this?

```
# STRONG PARAMS
permit_params do
  permitted = %i[one_param another_param]
  permitted << User::ACCOLADES
  permitted
end

# INPUT IN THE FORM
f.inputs "Accolades" do
  User::ACCOLADES.each do |accolade|
    f.input accolade, as: :boolean do
      f.check_box accolade, {}, "true", "false"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this wasn't the issue. It was a misinterpretation of the docs and missing strong params. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: If it is something with the strong params then you should try with the updated code